# Writing a rule in .htaccess to match the correct images folder location

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

In my single-page-webapp i used the html5 history API so that urls could have a REST pattern (/section1/stuff1..) and i'm planning to make a sort of a javascript router to navigate to several sections of the page depending on the url path.

Right now i'm still working on a local server(wamp) and i added a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

to the app root for that url's paths containing references to some sections of the page (e.g subdomain/sectionN) can redirect always to the index.php and the redirection was successful **BUT**   all external ressources failed to load and i got :

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/subdomain/section1/images/imgname.gif".
```

and it's logic because the images folder lies in the app root and not under a `/section1` folder and the .htaccess rule `RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]` should take only the `/images/imgname.gif` part and concatinate it after the `http://localhost/subdomain/`.

I found [this](http://wenda.soso.io/questions/2919226/rewrite-engine-htaccess-mime-type-error) as a similar problem so i rewrite the .htaccess file like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?section1/(.+)$ index.php/$1 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

but i got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 1):

These two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?section1/(.+)$ index.php/$1 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

will potentially both be applied to a single URL, because there is no `[L]` (last) tag after the first rule. So an URL like this:

```
section1/stuff/page1.html
```

will be converted to this by the first rule:

```
index.php/stuff/page1.html
```

and then will get fed into the second rule and converted to this:

```
index.php/index.php/stuff/page1.html
```

This is most likely what is causing the 500 internal server error. If you add `[L]` to the first rule then the second rule won't be applied in the case that the first rule matched the URL and was applied:

```
RewriteRule ^/?section1/(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you don't want your image URLs to be rewritten, then just remove the second `RewriteRule` (which actually makes the `[L]` redundant).

Comment: i moved the [L] from the last line to the previous but still get the 500 error because actually both rules are required for the redirection as even the url http://localhost/subdomain/section1 should be processed by the rule in last line (RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1) as section1 itself is just a sub-element of the DOM and not a page.

Comment: changing the order of the two last lines didn't solve it because it looks like once the first RewriteRule is processed (the RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1) it won't give the hand to the next rule.

Comment: i did a mistake; it's not a serial processing what i need but that the RewriteRule ^/?section1/(.+)$ index.php/$1 rule should process only urls specific for some files extensions (.png, .jpg,..). how it can be possible ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give some examples of the input URLs and the desired outputs after the rules are applied?

Comment: You can do something like this if you want the rule to only apply to some extensions: RewriteRule ^/?section1/(.+(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ index.php/$1